# Passing by reference - operator overloading

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

In what cases do we pass objects by reference in operator overloading and why?
Also, in what cases is operator overloading useful(specific case)?

EDIT: Language: C++

Comment: In what language? (or at least, in what Context?). Please be aware that we will not simply do your homework for you.

Comment: C++. And its not homework. I am simply having trouble understanding operator overloading like where exactly do we use it?

Comment: Think about Vectors and how as mathematical objects you could add and subtract two Vectors from each other (in however many dimensions). The most natural way to express that in C++ or other OOP language would be to use `+` and `-`. That's what operator overloading is about.

Comment: Can't that be done with normal functions? (just asking)

Comment: Yes, of course it _can_. The point is that it is natural to write `vec3 = vec1 + vec2;` and overloading the `+` makes expressing that addition of two vectors very intuitive.

Comment: Thanks I get it now. But the thing that still bothers me is why do we pass the objects by reference?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that - I suggest a new question (after searching the site first, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass parameters "by reference" either because you want to modify them (which is something you probably don't want to for operators, see below), or simply because it's more efficient to pass a simple pointer than to copy a whole object.

As for "why overload", that's mostly a matter of preference. There are some classic examples, like having a vector class that will let you add vectors or something similar -- basically, these are all good examples because they apply the same *meaning* that the arithmetic operators have to some new classes: whether you add integers or vectors, it's a natural notation to write "x+y" in both cases. This is also the classical reason for using constant references -- if you write "a=b+c" you don't expect b or c to be modified, and it is definitely good practice to only overload operators if the result of what you are doing is what the reader expects.

Things like smart pointers (or iterators, or other things that "pretend" to be pointers) like to overload operators such as -> or * (the dereference operator, not the multiplication). Same reason, these objects pretend to be pointers, they are meant to be used like pointers, so operator overloading is used to make them look more like pointers.

I have also overloaded the "," operator to feed parameters into a string formatting object -- because it looked good. STL uses overloads for "<<" and ">>" for the same reason; they figured it makes things easier to read.

Recently, I have overloaded a few arithmetic operators and "==" so I can write linear equations in mathematical notation. The code around that builds the coefficient matrix from readable source code, instead of requiring the developer to write a bunch of meaningless numbers. This is also an example where nonconstant references are being used -- however, the *result* of all this is a row in a matrix representing the equation, so it's precisely what the reader expects.

Basically, stick to one important rule: don't ever do anything unexpected. Overload operators only if the resulting notation like "a+b" is really what someone who doesn't know the internals of your overload expects it to be.

Comment: Thank alot for solving my problem :D

Comment: Sorry for all that text, but when I start typing...

Comment: well that was the most appropriate and informative answer, cleared everything.

Answer (score 0):

One of the tenants of cpp is that user types should look/behave like built in types (like int).

So if you can do

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
```

Then you should also be able to do

```
UserType e = ...;
UserType d = ...;
UserType f = e + d;
```

So operator overloading allows you to define operators +/-* etc... for your user defined types just like the built in types...

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and answering a part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful when you want to naturally express some aspect of objects of some type. For example, compiler knows how +, -, *, / applied to int and double. But it doesn't know how + applied to strings (the arrays of chars). It can't always concatenate arrays because it would be nonsense. But for the particular set of arrays (arrays of char) concatenation can be naturally expressed with symbol '+', so when we write (we probably don't, because we have std::string) some string class, we overload operator+(const MyString& rhs) which adds to our string the contents of another.

But operator overloading also can be used with not only your own types. For instance, you have a struct which represents an IPv4 address:

```
struct IpAddress
{
    unsigned int addr;
};
```

and you need something, that would help you printing this struct on the screen, or writing it to file. You could add function to_str() which would break addr into 4 components and return the string representation, but more natural way is to overload operator<< of ostream:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const IpAddress& ip)
{
    os 
        << (ip.addr >> 24) << '.' 
        << (0xff & (ip.addr >> 16)) << '.'
        << (0xff & (ip.addr >> 8)) << '.'
        << (0xff & ip.addr); 

    return os;
}
```

so now you don't have problems writing ip addresses to file or screen:

```
IpAddress ip;
// put something to ip

cout << "your address is: " << ip << endl;

ofstream f("log.txt");
f << "address: " << ip << endl;
```

very natural.

p.s. of course assuming that sizeof(int) == 4 ;)

Comment: Hmm that was very nice expample. Thanks a lot.